# Easiest way to create a Subversion Repository?

Tags: svn

We wrote batch files a while ago that automatically creates Subversion Repositories. Due to someone else's mistake, we lost the batch files. These batch files were at least 50 hours worth of work to set up.

Now, before I proceed and redo these batch files, I was wondering if there is an easy way or perhaps a program that can:

1. Automatically copy an existing Subversion repo into a new repo
2. Modify various config files to include new login details and passwords
3. Automatically deploy to a server

Is there something like this?

Comment: This has to do with a variety of things --> a) changing the cpanel details so deploy scripts can run and deploy to a specific server, b) grab the LATEST copy of the source code from another repo, c) automatically configuring it on a specific hosting account etc. I want to know if there are specific deployment strategies in place that will stop me from doing batch files manually...

Comment: git sucks and should never have been invented.